# CSS to protect overlapping of text with image

Tags: html, css

I have created a image with some text as shown in figure.

```
<span class="productname ">Excusite Beauty</span>
<img src="xy.jpg" data-attr="productimg" class="productimg " />
```

My css is

```
.productimg
{
float:right;
margin-top:15px;
height:120px;
margin-right:2%;
border:2px double  #0ff;
width:150px;
right:0px;
position:absolute;
}
.productname
{
font-size:1.2em;
display:block;
float:left;
}
```

[image]

How can i protect the overlapping of text and put the text in next line if it is long.
How to do it using css...plz help

[image]
after removing position and right=0

Comment: Including the code and an image is helpful, thank you for that, but it would be best to create a [codepen](http://codepen.io/)  of your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are absolutely positioning the product image. This takes it out of the normal "flow" of the document, and will cause this overlap.

Remove `position: absolute` from `.productimg` (you can go ahead and remove `right:0px;` as well) , and the text should wrap around the image properly. To allow the text to float around the image, you can either move it before `.productname` or float `.productname` and give it a width.

**[codepen](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/KtFDs)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="product">
  <img src="xy.jpg" data-attr="productimg" class="productimg " />
  <span class="productname ">Excusite Beauty</span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.productimg {
  float:right;
  /* margin-top:15px; */
  height:120px;
  border:2px double  #0ff;
  width:150px;
}
.productname {
  font-size:1.2em;
  display:block;
   width:150px
}
.product {
  width:300px;
}
```

Comment: Did you see my codepen example: [link](http://codepen.io/NickTomlin/pen/KtFDs). This allows for your image to stay in the same place. You will need to declare a width for the containing ``div`` (or whatever element you choose) but the text will wrap around your image.